# DataGridComboxBox is not shown in initial state

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridviewcombobox

After wasting 2 day, I just little understand of wpf datagrid data-binding process.In the Earlier,I want to show combo box in datagrid view column.After googled, i found the way to bind combo in datagrid.Now i got the problem that looks like easy but it make me crazy.

This is Initial state.In this state,Combo box is missing.

[image]

After double click the row,it visible.

[image]

How can i show combo box in Initial state? Thank You.

Comment: non explain down vote is useless for community.

Answer (score 1):

There'are two templates used in DataGrid:

1. CellTemplate
2. CellEditingTemplate

CellTemplate acts a role of, as you said, initial state, whereas CellEditingTemplate is used when you edit a cell. For instance, DataGridTextColumn is actually looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeField}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeField}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks you for showing me example of Cell Template and Cell Editing Template.

Comment: Please can you explain me for another problem?:)

Comment: @Jze Go ahead :)

Comment: After updated the cell value of datagrid, List in Viewmodel will auto update? Let me show you example=>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020099/observablecollection-is-not-update-after-datagrid-cell-change Thanks