# ObservableCollection is not update after DataGrid Cell Change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new in `wpf` and `mvvm databinding`. Now i am trying to make crud process with data gird. I have a problem to updateing process.I want to get update value after data grid cell updated by mvvm process.

Model

```
public class EmployeeType : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _EmpType;
        public string EmpType
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpType;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_EmpType !=value)
                {
                    _EmpType = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("EmpType");
                }
            }
        }

        string _EmpTypeDesc;
        public string EmpTypeDesc
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpTypeDesc;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_EmpTypeDesc!=value)
                {
                    _EmpTypeDesc = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("EmpTypeDesc");
                }
            }
        }

        bool _OTRounding;
        public bool OTRounding
        {
            get
            {
                return _OTRounding;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_OTRounding!=value)
                {
                    _OTRounding = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("OTRounding");
                }
            }
        }

        decimal _EarlyOTTimeBuffer;
        public decimal EarlyOTTimeBuffer
        {
            get
            {
                return _EarlyOTTimeBuffer;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_EarlyOTTimeBuffer!=value)
                {
                    _EarlyOTTimeBuffer = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("EarlyOTTimeBuffer");
                }
            }
        }

        string _EarlyOTRounding;
        public string EarlyOTRounding
        {
            get
            {
                return _EarlyOTRounding;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_EarlyOTRounding!=value)
                {
                    _EarlyOTRounding = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("EarlyOTRounding");
                }
            }
        }  

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void RaisePropertyChange(string prop)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged !=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
```

View Model

```
class EmployeeTypeViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<EmployeeType> _EmployeeTypeList = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeType>();       
        private ObservableCollection<TimeFormat> _ThreeTimeFormat = new ObservableCollection<TimeFormat>();

        public ObservableCollection<TimeFormat> ThreeTimeFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return _ThreeTimeFormat;
            }
            set
            {
                _ThreeTimeFormat = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ThreeTimeFormat");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeType> EmployeeTypeList
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmployeeTypeList;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmployeeTypeList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EmployeeTypeList");
            }
        }        

        public EmployeeType _SelectedEarlyOTRounding;
        public EmployeeType SelectedEarlyOTRounding
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedEarlyOTRounding;
            }
            set
           {
                if (_SelectedEarlyOTRounding != value)
                {
                    _SelectedEarlyOTRounding = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEarlyOTRounding");

                }
            }
        }


        public EmployeeTypeViewModel()
        {
            _EmployeeTypeList = DataAccess.EmployeeTypeDataAccessor.GetAllEmployeeTypes();           
            ThreeTimeFormat = TMSHelper.GetThreeTimeFormat();
        }
    }
```

View

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ViewModels:EmployeeTypeViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <DataGrid Margin="10,10,9.6,10.2" x:Name="empgrid" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeTypeList,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmpType" Binding="{Binding EmpType,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="OTRounding" Binding="{Binding OTRounding}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding EmpTypeDesc}"/>               
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Early OT Time Buffer" Binding="{Binding EarlyOTTimeBuffer}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Early OT Time Rounding">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ThreeTimeFormat,ElementName=empgrid}" SelectedValue="{Binding EarlyOTRounding,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEarlyOTRounding}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

I just realized things is if I changed value in datagrid cell,It's will auto update the `EmployeeTypeList` in viewmodel.Because i added `mode=twoway` in `itemsource` of grid.right? But when i debug, Set of EmployeeTypeList never happen.Why? if my doing process is wrong,please let me known how to do that? If you don't understand,please let me known.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just don't understand to binding completly at this point and it is okay.

`Mode=TwoWay` means that binded property will be changed on the UI when value is changed in the underlying object and also when user change the value on the UI.

In your case you should have to replace collection on the UI to notice the change. So, far you are changing content of the `ObservableCollection` and because of that you are not getting any notification on collection level. You should have get notification for `EmpType` when you change it on the UI.

Is it clear?

Comment: Please can you explain with example? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if any example really exists for this case. Collection is a complex object and it can be hardly constructed on the UI. I am maybe little bit confused and didn't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Lwin The setter for the collection property will be called **only** when somebody **assigns a new collection to the property**. The UI will never, never do that. Think through what's happening: When you change the value of a property of an object *in* the collection, that action does not create a new collection. Why would it? How could it? Why would you want it to? When you set property A of instance B of class C, you call the setter of that property on that instance of that class, not the setter of some other random property on some random other class.

Comment: @cloudikka , Yep Currently i am trying to learn mvvm structure and no code-behind.I am window form developer and i just want to upgrade my knowledge.but as you known,window form and wpf mvvm data binding structure are quite different.Now, I just want to known update process of datagrid and mvvm.How to trigger value change in datagrid?Do i need to add cell value change event to datagrid like window form?

Answer (score 0):

> One of the BindingMode values. The default is Default, which returns
>   the default binding mode value of the target dependency property.
>   However, the default value varies for each dependency property. In
>   general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes
>   and check boxes, default to two-way bindings, whereas most other
>   properties default to one-way bindings.

(source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx) )

so generally where it is possible to edit usually does not need to inform

now, for your combobox to work correctly try this.

I usually use it and works perfectly

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Early OT Time Rounding" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="Key"  
                        SelectedValuePath="Value" 
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding EarlyOTRounding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                        >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ThreeTimeFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="280" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ThreeTimeFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**attention to this**
`DataGridComboBoxColumn` must have a `SelectedValueBinding` property set to being an item in your `EmployeeTypeList` so that the selected value is changed in the list

in your case:

`SelectedValueBinding="{Binding EarlyOTRounding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Thanks you, I think DataGridComboBoxColumn is useful for nowmal design, I have to do customize combo(eg.two column in combo) .so i used this design.